# Multifunction POST method in apex REST API controller

Tags: apex, rest-api, post

I want to create a single POST method which takes method as a parameter along with the Request body. Using the parameter string method i'm trying to call the related method within my apex controller. But everytime I call this REST API using workbench and passing the method value i'm getting null value for method.

**

```
@RestResource(urlMapping='/AutomationSFEndPoint/*')
    global without sharing class Automation_SFEndPoint{
        @HttpPost
        global static String handleMethod(string method){
            if(method == 'Create_something'){
                //have some logic
            }
            if(method == 'Create_somethingElse'){
                //have some logic
            }
        }
    }
    //debug log for method is coming null every time
```

**

Comment: Welcome to SFSE. I don't see a question articulated here or enough detail to be sure about what's wrong. Could you please take a moment to review [ask] and [help/on-topic], then [edit] your post to add more details so the community can help you?

Comment: Please also show us what is your request body, request URL and I dont see a return statement. Please also paste full code for `handleMethod` but remove the business logic. It might be returning null correctly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In order for this to work, you need to format your request in a very specific way. First, the Content-Type header must be set to `application/json` or `application/xml`. Then, you must provide the appropriate JSON or XML:

## JSON

```
{ "method": "Hello World" }
```

## XML

```
<request>
  <method>Hello World</method>
</request>
```

You can read more [in the documentation](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_rest_methods.htm).